# Using SSL with Integrated Windows Authentication in Intranet

Tags: windows, iis, ssl, windows-authentication, intranet

Is it possible to have my website require SSL if it is using Windows Authentication?

So far, I'm not having luck with it.

Comment: Do you want it to require SSL only if Windows authentication is used or do you want SSL to be an always-on thing?

Comment: The site will always be using Windows authentication. SSL should always be in effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are always using Windows Authentication and always using SSL then the following should fit the scenario.
1. Rurn off all other forms of authentication in IIS.
2. Setup a redirect site in IIS to redirect all HTTP traffic to the HTTPS site (on the same server).

This forces all HTTP traffic over to SSL and only allows for Windows authentication.

Note this may behave strangely for non-IIS browsers due to how Windows Authentication works.

Comment: The steps above should get you what you need.  This is a pretty standard setup.

Comment: I had already tried that. Weird thing is, the site won't load/render at all with https if it's using Windows authentication. We're using a self-signed certificate by the way.

Comment: What browser(s) are you using? Does it work with anon access?

Comment: Internet Exploder. It does work with anonymous, and non-SSL. But since I have never tried SSL with Windows auth, I thought that maybe it wasn't even possibe (or even redundant). If you're sure it should work, it must be a problem with my SSL certificate.

Comment: Does the client trust the self-signed cert?

Comment: Yes. I can get the certificate to work with other sites on the server which allow anonymous access.